# Rational distance between any pair of an infinite set on a specific circle

Tags: geometry, rational-numbers, pythagorean-triples

Is it possible to find an infinite set of point belonging to the circle of radius r such that $\sqrt{r} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and where the distance between any pair is rational?
For example, can we find such set for $r=\frac{4}{3}$
This is related to the following question: [nD SPACE RATIONAL DISTANCE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982614/is-it-possible-to-find-an-infinite-set-of-points-in-the-4d-5d-nd-space-where)
The difference is the new condition on the radius (in the link, the argument is given for the unit circle).
My idea would be then to construct infinite sets in n-dimensional spaces considering the unions of such circles in 2D subspaces (and adding points on an axis when n is odd)

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt the method documented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978458). In that method, the circle's radius is 1, and the method to determine each point from the previous was to use the right-angled triangle with legs $3/5$ and $4/5$ and hypotenuse 1.

Now scale things up by a factor of 5. The radius is now $r=5$. $r$ is rational but $\sqrt r$ is not. We now use copies of the Pythagorean triangle with legs $3$ and $4$ and hypotenuse $5$. Choose each point to be at distance 3 from the previous. (Or distance 4; it doesn't matter which leg is used as chords of the circle.)